# Java Regex: Capture Multiple Matches on the same Line

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create a regex expression that would match one or multiple variable value assignments on the same line. I am using the following expression:

```
([a-z][a-zA-Z0-9-]*)=(('(\'|[^\'])*')|("(\"|[^"])*"))
```

For example, if I have the following string as input:

```
a="xyz" b="hello world"
```

And using the following code:

```
Matcher matcher = rules.get(regex).matcher(input);
int start = 0;

while (matcher.find(start)) {
    System.err.println(matcher.group(0));

    start = matcher.end();
}
```

It should give me two seperate results:

```
1. a="xyz"
2. b="hello world"
```

But it only returns one, the entire input string.

```
a="xyz" b="hello world"
```

It seems to be taking `xyz" b="hello world` as the inner part. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Your alternatives are off, see `([a-z][a-zA-Z0-9-]*)=(('([^']*)')|("([^"]*)"))`, [demo](https://regex101.com/r/2gp6HA/1)

Comment: Can you have escape `"` like `a="xyz" b="hell\"o world"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It was a mistake in typing the pattern, check again because mine is a bit different.

Comment: @anubhava Yea. I had a small mistake in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
(?s)([a-z][a-zA-Z0-9-]*)=(?:'([^\\']*(?:\\.[^\\']*)*)'|"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IG6tkq/2)

In Java,

```
String regex = "(?s)([a-z][a-zA-Z0-9-]*)=(?:'([^\\\\']*(?:\\\\.[^\\\\']*)*)'|\"([^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*)\")";
```

**Details**

- `(?s)` - inline `Pattern.DOTALL` embedded flag option that matches `.` match line break chars, too
- `([a-z][a-zA-Z0-9-]*)` - Group 1
- `=` - an equals sign
- `(?:'([^\\']*(?:\\.[^\\']*)*)'|"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)")` - a non-capturing group matching one of the two alternatives:

  - `'([^\\']*(?:\\.[^\\']*)*)'` - `'`, then any amount of chars other than `\` and `'` followed with 0+ repetitions of any escape sequence followed with 0+ chars other than `\` and `'`
  - `|` - or
  - `"([^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*)"` - `"`, then any amount of chars other than `\` and `"` followed with 0+ repetitions of any escape sequence followed with 0+ chars other than `\` and `"` .